# LibGDX - Dynamically change particle emitter's Atlas Region?

Tags: libgdx, particles

Is it possible to dynamically change the Atlas Region used by a particle emitter?

I've tried...

`effect.getEmitters().get(0).setImagePath("[someAtlasRegionName]");`

...but it continues to use the original region the effect was loaded with.

There appears to be a `.setSprite(Sprite)` method but it doesn't work with TextureAtlas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the `Sprite`'s fields to set it to the `TextureRegion` works (`Sprite` extends `TextureRegion`, so it has all the relevant fields):

```
Sprite s = effect.getEmitters().get(0).getSprite();
s.setTexture(vessel.getTexture());
s.setU (someAtlasRegion.getU());
s.setU2(someAtlasRegion.getU2());
s.setV (someAtlasRegion.getV());
s.setV2(someAtlasRegion.getV2());
effect.getEmitters.get(0).setImagePath(someRegionName);
```

**Edit**: I don't know if `ParticleEmitter.setImagePath()` matters or not, but I'd include that as well just in case - it definitely won't hurt. So I added that as well.